# how to specify github pw when using "gcloud app deploy" for a node project

Tags: node.js, github, npm, gcloud

My node app is on the big side, so it is split into a number of npm packages.  These packages are hosted in private repos on github.

Locally on my pc, I clone the repo, npm init, get prompted for password, npm run and all is good.

Now I'm trying to deploy to google cloud app engine (newbie in google cloud).
Tutorial says to add a file called app.yaml with content

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
```

Then I enter "gcloud app deploy".  The first reported error is

```
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/johngrabner/moch_time.git
```

How do I provide my password for gcloud so it can pull private packages?

Or, is "gcloud app deploy" just not mature enough?

Or, is using and storing private npm packages in github a strange way of structuring my project?

Comment: When you clone your repository into your gcloud local machine, does it ask for credentials? Do you authenticate when you use the gcloud command?

Comment: windows environment appears to cache my github password behind the scenes.  On raspberry, you need to setup git credential.helper explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gcloud command does not provide an option to include a password when deploying an app. If you want to specify your credentials to access your private GitHub repositories, you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/access-private-github-repos).

Before starting with the steps indicated in the previous tutorial, you should generate a new SSH for GitHub authentication. The steps to do so are [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

Alternatively, you can connect your GitHub repo to a GCP repository using Source Repositories (follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories) to learn how to do it). This also allows to store your credentials for further use.

Comment: Thank you.  GCP repository approach appears to be the most straightforward. Creating the 4 mirrors (one for the app, and 3 for each package dependency), I updated the package.json to now refer to the clones in gcloud.  On the command line, npm install worked fine.  But when I tried "gcloud app deploy" I got the following error "Step #1: npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://source.developers.google.com/p/purple01-192114/r/moch_time.git".  I tried this command from the gcloud console and it works.  So looks like most straight forward approach does not work.

Comment: When you mention that it works in the gcloud console, do you mean you are using [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/)? Does this mean that your app is deployed now? If not, have you tried importing your npm packages to your local machine (or Cloud Shell) and deployed from there?

Comment: So far my solution is: do npm install on my local machine, copy everything over as part of a docker build, then run the docker file on a vm.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found that Docker / Kubernetes is probably a better choice for deployment.  A number of courses and online video listed "no more, it works on my machine, but not in production".

You package your app in Docker, where you specify the exact OS, middleware, etc.  Test on your machine.  Then deploy this image to Azure, AWS, or Google.  Kubernetes manages the spaning of these images.