# Can not deploy to Google App Engine because of NPM Install script (IPFS and NodeJS) "Host key verification failed."

Tags: node.js, web-services, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

There's a lot of "I think" going on here.

But I can't deploy my project to the Google App Engine.

"I think" it's be cause I'm installing the javascript IPFS library, and it does some sort of compiling or something using "assemblyscript".

The error message is "Host key verification failed."
And "fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Any suggestion on how get around this problem.

Here is the relevant part of the log

The most common suggestion I'm seeing is to upgrade NPM which isn't an option in my case, as it happening during to Google App Engine build.

```
Step #6 - "builder": Running "npm ci --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)"
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! Error while executing:
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/assemblyscript/assemblyscript.git
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! and the repository exists.
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
Step #6 - "builder": 
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2021-03-15T22_15_17_871Z-debug.log
Step #6 - "builder": Done "npm ci --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)" (12.232429128s)
Step #6 - "builder": Failure: (ID: beaf8772) npm ERR! Error while executing:
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/assemblyscript/assemblyscript.git
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! and the repository exists.
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
Step #6 - "builder": 
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #6 - "builder": npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2021-03-15T22_15_17_871Z-debug.log
Step #6 - "builder": --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #6 - "builder": Running "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-5577006791947779410 /builder/outputs/output"
Step #6 - "builder": Done "mv -f /builder/outputs/output-5577006791947779410 /builder/o..." (9.224989ms)
Step #6 - "builder": ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
Finished Step #6 - "builder"
```

Comment: Have you visited this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57215411/8753991)?

Comment: I'll go over it, but I don't think it helps because it's not a private repo

Comment: same problem with not-private repo